# Orthogonality relationship for solutions to the wave equation

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, orthogonality

If I have two plane waves $e^{i k \cdot x}$ and $e^{i k' \cdot x}$ for $x, k, k' \in \mathbb{R}^d$, I can consider them to be orthogonal in the sense that $$\int d^dx e^{i k \cdot x} \overline{e^{i k' \cdot x}} = \delta^d(k-k').$$

Now I want to restrict them to solve to the wave equation in Minkowski spacetime $\Box \phi(x) = 0$, where $\Box := \partial_0^2 - \sum_{i = 1}^{d-1} \partial_{i}^2$. This means I need to have $k^2 = k'^2 = 0$, and I'd like to enforce this using a Dirac delta function, so that I consider a basis of solutions to the equation to be $$\Phi_k(x) :=\delta(k^2)e^{i k \cdot x}.$$

I then want write down an orthogonality condition on these basis elements, and I arrive at $$\int d^dx \delta(k^2) e^{i k \cdot x} \overline{\delta(k'^2)e^{i k' \cdot x}} = \delta(k^2)\delta(k'^2)\delta^d(k-k') = \delta(k^2)^2\delta^d(k-k'),$$ where in the last equality I set $k'^2 = k^2$ on support of $\delta^d(k-k')$.

It's clear to me that I'm missing something here, because I don't want to have the square of the Dirac delta function. So how can I write down an orthogonality relationship between $\Phi_k(x)$ and $\Phi_{k'}(x)$ that doesn't introduce $\delta(k^2)^2$?

If I restrict to $k^2 = k'^2 = 0$ without using the Dirac delta function and instead think of these as some additional constraints that I enforce algebraically then I end up with $\delta^d(k-k')$ constrained to $k^2 = k'^2 = 0$. Then I seem to have shifted the problem so that I now have two null vectors which cover only a $d-1$ dimensional subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$, but they're set equal using a $d$ dimensional delta function. For my usage case I anyway need to keep in the Dirac delta function.

Comment: Possibly relevant earlier question of mine: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4172734/orthogonality-of-generalized-eigenbases-of-self-adjoint-operators

Answer (score -1):

The plane wave solutions of the d'Alembert equation $\Box{}\,\phi(x)=0$ are
$$
\phi(x)=e^{i\,k\cdot x}\,,\quad\quad k\cdot x:=k_0x_0-k_1x_1-k_2x_2-k_3x_3\,,
$$
with
$$
k^2=k_0^2-k_1^2-k_2^2-k_3^2=0\,.
$$
(I am not sure why you multiply $\phi(x)$ by $\delta(k^2)\,.$) Clearly,
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^4} e^{i\,k\cdot x}e^{-i\,k'\cdot x}\,dx=\int_{\mathbb R^4} e^{i\,(k-k')\cdot x}\,dx=(2\pi)^4\delta(k-k')\,.
$$
See p. xxi of Peskin & Schroeder, *An Introduction to Quantum Field Theory*. The extension to $d$ dimensions is obvious.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. The $\delta(k^2)$ enforces the on-shell condition that you gave,  that $k^2 =0$. I already have the orthogonality condition that you give at the start of my question, so this doesn't answer my question. I'm specifically asking how to work with the orthogonality condition when the Dirac delta is included

Comment: As far as I can tell the [on-shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_shell_and_off_shell) condition $k^2=0$ does not have to be enforced by multiplying the solution $\phi$ satisfying it by your delta function. Pls cite a reference if I am missing something.

Comment: yes you are correct that it's possible to encode the on-shell condition without using the delta function. In my question I addressed this in the last paragraph, and also discussed in that paragraph why I still find there to be a problem when enforcing $k^2=0$ algebraically as you have done. My usage case is based on extending to this problem, which is why I need to use the Dirac delta; https://mathoverflow.net/questions/398360/space-of-solutions-to-a-fourth-order-wave-equation

Comment: I still don't get it: The answer by Igor Kavkine to that MO question of yours uses the Dirac delta together with the *Fourier transform* of $\phi(x)\,,$ that is, $\hat\phi(k)\,.$ How the wave equation for $\phi(x)$ and the equation for $\hat\phi(k)$ are related please see for example [this reference](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m267/pdeft.pdf).